# 2 div inline but with centered h1, like if second div wasn't there

Tags: html, css

i have a complex issue. I hope u understand my problem.

There is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/User1010/ZNGsh/110/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="header-e1">
    <h1>
    TITLE
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="header-e2">
<p>
       Line 1
    <br>
    Line 2
</p>

</div>

</div>
```

What i actually want is the H1 - Title to be centered like in the nav div.

But the second div (header-e2) needs to be floating next to the first div(header-e1) and move down if the width get's too low.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with flexbox

As your question is  quite unclear about:

> But the second div (header-e2) needs to be floating next to the first
>   div(header-e1) and move down if the width get's too low.-

I'll give you a few examples

1. #### `H2` floating next to `H1` but close to the side of the page not to `H1`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue
}

#header-e1 {
  margin: auto
}

#header div {
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-e1">
    <h1>
      TITLE
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="header-e2">
    <p>
      Line 1
      <br> Line 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. #### `H2` floating next to `H1` and next to `H1`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  background: lightblue
}


#header div {
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-e1">
    <h1>
      TITLE
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="header-e2">
    <p>
      Line 1
      <br> Line 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close. Make #header-e2 200 pixels wide and you'll see the issue. Title is not centered relative to the header which is - if I understand the PO correct - the intention.

Comment: close is close enough for me because the second div wont be to wide.